# open() - Opening a file created via UI vs. via Console

Tags: python, function, file

I am starting Python and this is my first question on Stack Overflow.
I was doing some files handling recently and came up to an Error when trying to open a file to test it.

```
f = open("fi.txt", "r")
```

The problem is, I always run into an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Beginner\FileHandle2.py", line 9, in <module>
f = open("fi.txt", 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fi.txt'
```

The path has been specified (via sys.path).
The file exist and it is placed in the same folder as my Python script (which is FileHandle2.py).
I do not understand what I am doing wrong here, if someone could give me some hint?

Moreover, when I do the following:

```
with open("fi2.txt",'w',encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
   f.write("my first file\n")
```

The file "fi2.txt" is correctly created in my folder and I can call it without error when doing:

```
f = open("testy.txt", 'r')
```

Hence, I would like some hint on what is going on?
"fi.txt" was created with the UI (in Windows 10, right click > New > Text Document) while "fi2.txt" was created via the Python console.

Until now I know what to do, but I wanted to have explanation on this behavior.
Thank you peeps!

Comment: I'd take a look at the current working directory of python at time of execution. `import os` `print(os.getccwd())` and then make sure your file is in the correct location `print(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))`

Comment: Python only uses `sys.path` for locating .py modules during `import`, not for arbitrary data files. You will need to specify the complete path to the file or change the current working directory so it's the one the file is in.

Comment: Thank you both for your answer! The LazyScripter, I did check this command to print the current working directory, and I was indeed in the correct directory where my fi.txt and my Python file were.
Martineau, I also specified the full paths in different way, with double \\, single \, or even the other way around / and // but couldn't find a resolution.

Comment: Since it is working when I create the file in Python and open it later, this issue of mine is not really an emergency, hopefully it will not stuck me later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why, and it is really dumb.
When you create a Text file on Windows 10, you don't actually need to add the .txt extension, Windows 10 automatically add it. Also, the text files will show no extension as well.

I was quite used to type the extension myself tbh, so I never paid attention about the text files I was making.

Basically, on VS Code, the name of my file was:

```
fi.txt.txt
```